# Not getting multiple records result in foreach

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get each objects points and finally I need to add those points.

I am using foreach loop, but I get only one objects points as a result.

Please help me to get all objects points as sum

```
MODEL:

 public function getTransactionPoint($transactionId)

    {

        $transaction       = Transaction::find($transactionId);
        $transactionCoupon = TCoupon::where('transaction_id', '=', $transactionId)->first();
        $transactionPoint  = TPoint::where('transaction_id', '=', $transactionId)->first();
        $pointType         = PointType::find($this->pointUser->point_type_id);



   //to get transaction details

                      $trans_detail = DB::table('jocom_transaction_details AS a')
                                ->select('a.*',  'b.*')
                    ->leftJoin('jocom_products AS b', 'a.sku', '=', 'b.sku')
                    ->where('a.transaction_id', '=', $transactionId)->get();

//for bpoints

        if($pointType->type == 'BCard' )

        { 

            foreach ($trans_detail as  $value) 
          {



               $date1=$value->valid_from;
               $date2=$value->valid_to;

              $startdate=strtotime($date1);
              $enddate=strtotime($date2);
              $in_range=false;
              $out_of_range=false;
              $nodate=false;
              $today1= date("Y-m-d");
              $today=strtotime($today1);



                if(($today >= $startdate) && ($today <=$enddate)) 
                {

                  $in_range=true;
                }

                else
                {

                  $in_range=false;
                  $out_of_range=true;
                }


        if($in_range)
        {


           if($value->multibpoints)

                    {
                  $points = $value->multibpoints *$value->price;
                    }

                    elseif($value->bpoints)

                    {

                        $points = $value->bpoints;

                    }


        }
        if($out_of_range)
        {
           $points = ($value->price) * $pointType->earn_rate;

        }
        if ($points - floor($points) > 0.99) {
            return floor($points) + 1;
        } else {
            return floor($points);
        }

            }//endforeach





        }else
              //for jpoints

            foreach ($trans_detail as $key=>$value) {

            $date3=$value->valid_from;
               $date4=$value->valid_to;

              $startdatee=strtotime($date3);
              $enddatee=strtotime($date4);
              $in_rangee=false;
              $out_of_rangee=false;
              $nodatee=false;
              $today3= date("Y-m-d");
              $today4=strtotime($today3);



                if(($today4 >= $startdatee) && ($today4 <=$enddatee)) 
                {
                  $in_rangee=true;
                }
                else
                {
                  $in_rangee=false;
                  $out_of_rangee=true;
                }


                       if($in_rangee)
        {

            if($value->multijpoints)

                 {
                    $points = $value->multijpoints * $value->price;
                  }

                  elseif ($value->jpoints) {
                      $points = $value->jpoints;
                  }

        }
        if($out_of_rangee)
        {

         $points = ($value->price) * $pointType->earn_rate;
        }



        if ($points - floor($points) > 0.99) {
            return floor($points) + 1;
        } else {
            return floor($points);
        }

        }

        }

    }
}
```

Suppose product A has 22 jpoints and 33 bpoints and product b has 10 jpooints and 12 bpoints, I am getting only points of A product, but I need output as sum of product a and product b points

am trying to get each objects points and finally i need to add those points .am using foreach loop .but i am getting only one objects points as a result please help me to get all objects points as sum``

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: am using laravel 4.2

Comment: I would imagine it's because of `$pointType->type == 'BCard'` which, according to the comment above it, is to tell whether it should return `bpoinst` or `jpoints`.

Comment: it shoud return bpoints

Comment: Sorry I miss understood your question. I'll put an answer in now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly, the reason you're only getting the results for one product is because you're using `return` inside the loop. Instead, you can define a variable called something like `$totalPoints`, add to it and then return that value after the loop e.g.

```
$totalPoints = 0;

foreach ($trans_detail as $value) {

    //The rest of the code

    if ($points - floor($points) > 0.99) {
        $totalPoints += floor($points) + 1;
    } else {
        $totalPoints += floor($points);
    }

}

return $totalPoints;
```

Also, you don't have to use this but it would appear you can greatly simplify your code:

```
public function getTransactionPoint($transactionId)
{
    $pointType = PointType::find($this->pointUser->point_type_id);

    $trans_detail = DB::table('jocom_transaction_details AS a')
        ->select('a.*', 'b.*')
        ->leftJoin('jocom_products AS b', 'a.sku', '=', 'b.sku')
        ->where('a.transaction_id', '=', $transactionId)->get();

    $pointsName = $pointType->type == 'BCard' ? 'bpoints' : 'jpoints';

    $totalPoints = 0;

    $today = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));

    foreach ($trans_detail as $value) {

        if ($today >= strtotime($value->valid_from) && $today <= strtotime($value->valid_to)) {
            $points = $value->multibpoints ? $value->multibpoints * $value->price : $value->$pointsName;
        } else {
            $points = ($value->price) * $pointType->earn_rate;
        }

        $totalPoints += $points - floor($points) > 0.99 ? floor($points) + 1 : floor($points);
    }

    return $totalPoints;
}
```